# Is it safe to use optoisolator for a longer period?

Tags: opto-isolator

I have the following optoisolator [PC817](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/Sharp/mXruvuu.pdf). It is a 4-Pin Phototransistor Optoisolator.
My idea is basically to control electrical appliances in my home. The power supply in my country is 230V 50Hz.

I specifically want to control tube lights in my room. The control of 5V comes from an AVR microcontroller.

My circuit connections are shown in the picture.[image: PC817 connections]

Hoping that my connections are correct, my question: is it safe to run them with optoisolator for a prolonged duration. And also how reliable are they?

I also want some suggestions on additional safety precautions.

Comment: That circuit won't work and will possibly hurt you when you power it. Please seek an expert advice and/or use a ready made commercial product if you don't know how to deal with the mains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuitdiagram has some very basic problems:

left side:
There is no series resistor for the LED to limit the current.

right side:
I don't see an power source. 
And if there were any: the max. voltage between C and E of the PC817 is allowed to be 35V. Don't be tempted to switch 230V with the transistor of the optoisolator. You must use something like a triac or thyristor to do the high voltage switching.

Comment: What I meant to show was just the switch socket. The power source and everything is already connected to the switch.

Comment: @Naveen Chakravarthy: And how are we supposed to know that there is not also a triac and you just didn't "mean to show" it?

Comment: Lol, can you suggest me any other Optoisolator that I can use for my requirements.

Comment: @Naveen Chakravarthy: see the one used in the linked question above, e.g. MOC3041 https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MO/MOC3041M.pdf (important: for 230V AC you have to use the 400V variant, 250V would not be enough). See application on p. 7

Comment: This one is great. Thanks. Seems like I should use a triac externally.